# Echo JSON in a d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, json, d3.js

I have a chart created using `d3.js` where if you hover over the months,the weekly scores are found.

Fiddle link to the chart I am talking about here : https://jsfiddle.net/qp7L1hob/1/

I also have a table in my DB where I maintain the record of the scores of the Employees every week.What you see here is only for four weeks - (week1 to week4) but in my DB I have record for all the weeks of the months.This is just for reference .

**Table pointsScored :** 
[image: score]
After the user logs in,I want to display only that person's relevant scores.Lets say if Rob logs in,his score for week1 is 47 , week2 is 44, week3 is 44 and week4 is 43.

**Issue :** I  am `Using php to extract json` from `SQL` server . Below `PHP` file does that.

**The problem is that how do I get the `JSON` into the `d3.js` file, i.e the above fiddle.**

please help.

`json` file (lets name it as `data.php`) :I understand that I need to include this `data.php` in the above `d3.js` file.But not sure how.

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "xxxxxxx";
$connectioninfo = array(
    'Database' => 'xxxxxx'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectioninfo);

if ($conn) {
    echo 'connection established';
}
else {
    echo 'connection failure';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}

$q1 = "SELECT WeekNumber,pointsRewarded,EmployeeID FROM pointsBadgeTable WHERE EmployeeID = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $q1);

if ($stmt == false) {
    echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}

do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}

while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first
echo json_encode($result); //You will get the encoded array variable

?>
```

Comment: Running the first code snippet gives `"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`

Comment: If you want to include PHP in your javascript, make sure your script is is located in your PHP file. if your javascript is in a different file, you might want to use an http request using $.ajax() to request your data from your PHP file.

Comment: @Kingsthor looks good.But its not working here.Anyways,thanks.

Comment: Did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794722/bringing-data-from-php-into-d3-js help you?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters unfortunately didn't. I checked it before posting the question as it was the only question in stackoverflow,related to my issue.Anyways,thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error? Otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: The error is that when I try to echo as I mentioned above,m not able to do so.The chart disappears if I try to echo using the above code in the "var dataWeeks" .M not sure what is the proper way to echo in a ds.js file.In an HTML,the above method works perfect.as can be seen right now the weeks info is static.I want to echo it there.Thanks @ Maximilian

Comment: Hope I am clear now.I am just trying to echo the week1,week2,... all those info .The value will be dynamic as it will vary from user to user,who logs in.

Comment: As Kigsthor said, you need to use ajax. Look at `json_encode` (php side) and  `JSON.parse` (javacript side). Php can get the data from de database and build the good array for you. After, you send this array with json_encode (transform array to string). The JS get this string and parse him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1: Returning JSON

Since you want your data back in `json` format,  then remember to set the content type in the response header, as well as remove the successful connection `echo`, since it'll mess up the results:

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "xxxxxxx";
$connectioninfo = array(
    'Database' => 'xxxxxx'
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectioninfo);
if (!$conn) {
    echo 'connection failure';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}

$q1 = "SELECT WeekNumber,pointsRewarded,EmployeeID FROM pointsBadgeTable WHERE EmployeeID = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $q1);
if ($stmt == false) {
    echo 'error to retrieve info !! <br/>';
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , TRUE));
}
do {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

//Set content type to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//Echo a json object to the browser
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

I would also recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) to connect to your database. Basically, like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=YouAddress;Database=YourDatabase", "Username", "Password");

$sql = "SELECT WeekNumber,pointsRewarded,EmployeeID FROM pointsBadgeTable WHERE EmployeeID = ':UserID'";

if($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)){

    //Bind the sessionID
    $stmt->bindParam('UserID', $_SESSION['id']);

    //Execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    //Fetch data
    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //Close cursor
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    //Set header type to json
    header("content-type:application/json");

    //Echo json encoded array
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Note that you might have to download the Microsoft server PDO drivers if you want to use PDO.

Microsoft has a demo page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff754357(v=sql.105).aspx), that explains how to use PDO with SQL Server.

#### 2: Communicating with the server

You need to be able to fetch the data from your PHP page. The best way to do this is via [`Ajax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

You need to send an Ajax request to the `data.php` file (Using jQuery's [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) for simplicity):

```
$.get("path/to/data.php", function(data){
  //`data` is the JSON that the server echoed 
});
```

Or, in vanilla JS:

```
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
      var data = httpRequest.responseText;

      //Do stuff with data here
    } 
  }
};
httpRequest.open('GET', "path/to/data.php");
httpRequest.send();
```

#### 3: Using the data

So now we have the data from the server, but it isn't in a useable format for the graph, what do we do?

According to your comments, the Ajax request returns data in a format like:

```
[{
    "WeekNumber": "week49",
    "pointsRewarded": 50,
    "EmployeeID": 100739
}, {
    "WeekNumber": "week51",
    "pointsRewarded": 50,
    "EmployeeID": 100739
}, {
    "WeekNumber": "week50",
    "pointsR‌​ewarded": 50,
    "EmployeeID": 100739
}]
```

However, looking over your JSFiddle, it's needed in a completely different format, so it's pretty obvious we need to change the format.

First of all, we'll need to parse the object, so we have all the correct data:

```
function ParseData(data) {

  var parsed = {};

  var months = ['January - 2016', 'February - 2016', 'March - 2016', 'April - 2016', 'May - 2016', 'June - 2016', 'July - 2016', 'August - 2016', 'September - 2016', 'October - 2016', 'November - 2016', 'December - 2016'];

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    var week = parseInt(item.WeekNumber.slice(4)),
      month = Math.floor((week - 1) / 4);

    if (!parsed[month]) parsed[month] = {
      weeks: [],
      points: 0,
      month: months[month - 1]
    }

    var weekLabel = "Week " + week + ": " + item.pointsRewarded;

    parsed[month].weeks.push(weekLabel);
    parsed[month].points += item.pointsRewarded;

  });

  return FormatData(parsed);
}
```

All we're doing there is looping through the results, and building an object with the relevant info. Next, we need to format the data so it works with the charts. Since we already have the parsed data, this is simple:

```
function FormatData(data) {

  var formatted = {
    points: [],
    weeks: [],
    months: []
  };

  for (var month in data) {

    var now = data[month];

    formatted.points.push(now.points);
    formatted.months.push(now.month);
    formatted.weeks.push(now.weeks.join("<br>"));
  }

  return formatted;
}
```

Now when you call `ParseData(ajaxData)`, it will return all the info you need for your charts.

[A working demo can be seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/2dy3dvuc/), with fake data.

Now all we need to do is wait to render the chart with the correct data. In this case, I wrapped all the code for the chart in it's own function, and make it so it uses the data passed to it in the `formattedData` parameter:

```
function InitChart(formattedData) {
  let colors = ['#67001f', '#b2182b', '#d6604d', '#f4a582', '#fddbc7', '#e0e0e0', '#bababa', '#878787', '#4d4d4d', '#1a1a1a', 'white', 'white'];


  var width = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetWidth,
    height = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetHeight,
    minOfWH = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    initialAnimDelay = 300,
    arcAnimDelay = 150,
    arcAnimDur = 3000,
    secDur = 1000,
    secIndividualdelay = 150;

  var radius = undefined;

  // calculate minimum of width and height to set chart radius
  if (minOfWH > 200) {
    radius = 200;
  } else {
    radius = minOfWH;
  }

  // append svg
  var svg = d3.select('.chart-wrapper').append('svg').attr({
    'width': width,
    'height': height,
    'class': 'pieChart'
  }).append('g');

  svg.attr({
    'transform': 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')'
  });

  // for drawing slices
  var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 0.6).innerRadius(radius * 0.45);

  // for labels and polylines
  var outerArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.85).outerRadius(radius * 0.85);

  // d3 color generator
  // let c10 = d3.scale.category10();

  var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
    return d;
  }).sort(null);

  var draw = function draw() {

    svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");
    svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");

    // define slice
    var slice = svg.select('.slices').datum(formattedData.points).selectAll('path').data(pie);
    slice.enter().append('path').attr({
      'fill': function fill(d, i) {
        return colors[i];
      },
      'd': arc,
      'stroke-width': '25px'
    }).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
      return 'rotate(-180, 0, 0)';
    }).style('opacity', 0).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
      return i * arcAnimDelay + initialAnimDelay;
    }).duration(arcAnimDur).ease('elastic').style('opacity', 1).attr('transform', 'rotate(0,0,0)');

    slice.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
      return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
    }).duration(secDur).attr('stroke-width', '5px');

    var midAngle = function midAngle(d) {
      return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
    };

    var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text").data(pie(formattedData.points));

    text.enter().append('text').attr('dy', '0.35em').style("opacity", 0).attr("cursor", "default").style('fill', function(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    }).text(function(d, i) {
      return formattedData.months[i];
    }).attr('transform', function(d) {
      // calculate outerArc centroid for 'this' slice
      var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
      // define left and right alignment of text labels
      pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
      return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
    }).style('text-anchor', function(d) {
      return midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
    }).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
      return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
    }).duration(secDur).style('opacity', 1);

    text.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
      tooltip.html(formattedData.weeks[i])
        .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 6 + 'px')
        .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 14 + 'px')
        .style("opacity", 1);
    }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
      tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
    });


    var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline").data(pie(formattedData.points));

    polyline.enter().append("polyline").style("opacity", 0.5).attr('points', function(d) {
      var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
      pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
      return [arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d)];
    }).transition().duration(secDur).delay(function(d, i) {
      return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
    }).attr('points', function(d) {
      var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
      pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
      return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos];
    });
  };

  draw();

  var button = document.querySelector('button');

  var replay = function replay() {

    d3.selectAll('.slices').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(0).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
    d3.selectAll('.lines').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(100).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
    d3.selectAll('.labels').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(200).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();

    setTimeout(draw, 800);
  };
}
```

Now, just put it all together and render the chart with the data:

```
$.get("path/to/data.php", function(data){
  //Get data
  var parsedData = ParseData(data);
  //Render chart
  InitChart(parsedData);
});
```

#### [You can see the fully updated JS file here.](http://pastebin.com/vAWQH2F1)

Don't forget to set the correct ajax URL.

Comment: thanks for the input.I will try with what you have said.I will get back to ya.

Comment: but how do I pull the data to the javascript of the above fiddle

Comment: @jane the `ajax` request returns the data.

Comment: Thanks.I will get back to ya.

Comment: Jacob , it should work without the PDO also i guess.

Comment: Also I am able to get the data ,no problem what so ever.But please tell me how do I use the get() in my javascript here.I have been searching for a solution everywhere,but no luck.i appreciate your help.Thanks.God bless @Jacob

Comment: @jane could you send me an example of what the ajax gets from the database?

Comment: When I run the data.php I get something like this. This is the exact data. But I want to put it in the tooltip of the chart.    ...................connection established[{"WeekNumber":"week49","pointsRewarded":50,"EmployeeID":100739},{"WeekNumber":"week51","pointsRewarded":50,"EmployeeID":100739},{"WeekNumber":"week50","pointsRewarded":50,"EmployeeID":100739}]

Comment: how do I put this data in the above chart.that what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I am pretty new.So kindly excuse me here.Thanks for all the help.

Comment: please use the fiddle link if you would like to test anyway

Comment: @jane there was a bit of an issue with the PHP, update to the new first codeblock in my answer(http://pastebin.com/Psgk5AXR), and send me what it outputs

Comment: doing so gives me this  array :

Comment: [{"WeekNumber":"week49","pointsRewarded":50,"EmployeeID":100739},{"WeekNumber":"week51","pointsRewarded":50,"EmployeeID":100739},{"WeekNumber":"week50","pointsRewarded":50,"EmployeeID":100739}]

Comment: Okay. I assume you want the data inserted into the chart per month, starting from january?

Comment: Yeah exactly.it would echo for every respective user who logs in and data.php is going to fetch it.for instance , the above data would be for december month.I have data for all other months too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132844/discussion-between-jane-and-jacob-gray).

Comment: issue is that get() is not fetching the desired data in the above code here.So the chart is not able to display it.